# Is it possible to use Samsung Galaxy Nexus as a bootable USB stick?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, usb, samsung-galaxy-nexus, linux

I want to install centOS linux distro on my desktop, which does not have a disk drive. Moreover, I posses a 4GB usb stick which is insufficient for installation. I need a usb stick with atleast 8GB to install centOS.

However, I've Galaxy Nexus which has lots of space. So I was wondering as to can I use it as a bootable USB stick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently an application on the Google Play Store called [DriveDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid) that should be able to handle that task. Please note that it needs a *rooted* phone.

After you install the app, it's a pretty straightforward process. If you need a helpful guide, this [How-to by LifeHacker](http://lifehacker.com/5990655/how-to-boot-into-linux-from-your-android-phone) should help.